# Trouble after update in Talend 8.0.1 . Impossible to find or load primary Class "myProject"."myJob"

Tags: java, maven, talend

I worked on my Talend Studio 8.0.1 for several month with no problem. But last week after an update on my git, I didn't succed to run any of my job. Here is the error message after run a job :

Erreur : impossible de trouver ou de charger la classe principale sandbox.tests_0_1.tests
Causé par : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sandbox.tests_0_1.tests
[image]

In english :

Error: Could not find or load main class sandbox.tests_0_1.tests
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sandbox.tests_0_1.tests

When I looked the error message in the C:\Talend\Talend-Studio-V8.0.1\workspace\ .metadata\ .log

Here is the error message :

ERROR org.talend.commons.exception.CommonExceptionHandler  - [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project routines: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example.sandbox.code:routines:jar:8.0.1: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0: Cannot access central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) in offline mode and the artifact org.junit:junit-bom:pom:5.7.1 has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]

Would you be able to help me with this issue please ?
Best Regards

Edit After the comment of Muhammed Ozbilici :
I tried what you propose to me, and the result is quite inexpected.
[image: Quite a lot of errors]

I had a problem with the folder containing the routine.jar file, I solved it by puting it in the correct compilation path I saw in Talend. But there is still a lot of problems and it dont seems to be just a single .jar file problem.

And now I dont have the error I speak about in the first time but I have this one :
[image]

Amine : I already try this solution but I still have my problem.
More precisely, I can run my jobs in local, but not on my git anymore.

Comment: check here please. https://community.talend.com/s/article/Debug-issues-related-to-the-Talend-Studio-error-Could-not-find-or-load-main-class-7Cs9y?language=en_US

Comment: Duplicate the job and re-run it or simply change the workspace

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Like I said, I had this error after my migration/update :
[image]

Maven parameters with this error :
[image]

Maven parameters without any error at all and all my job working perfectly well :
[image]

Apparently my update, forced this Offline mode to "on", if you remove this you fixed everything.

Thank you for your time guys.